# androidTest with external mocked ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-testing

My application combines 3 ContentProvider data sources into one UI.
I want to be sure everything is laid out correctly, hence I am trying to **provide mock content providers** with predefined data (and later take screenshots of that, but that's step 2).

The project structure is:

```
/app
/app/homeapp
/app/sourceapp
```

My main activity is in `/app/homeapp` and reads data from `/app/sourceapp` via a `ContentProvider`. It also reads some data from its own `ContentProvider`.

I want to be in control of the data during the test. A sample test looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class MainAppActivityTest {
    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MusicHomeActivity_> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MusicHomeActivity_.class);

    @Test
    public void testDataDisplayed() throws Exception {
        // Check view in target.
        // Ensure items are displayed properly.
        // Take screenshot, compare.
    }
}
```

(It is based on the new **AndroidJUnit4** class).

Within `src/androidTest/AndroidManifest.xml` I'm actually able to create a new stubbed `ContentProvider` like this:

```
<manifest
    package="com.company.app"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application>

        <provider
            android:name="com.company.app.DataContentProviderStubbed"
            android:authorities="com.company.app.data.stubbed"
            android:exported="true"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Now my key problem is how to set that `DataContentProviderStubbed` as default provider. 
I can not override the authority or give it an higher priority, the system will refuse this (only one ContentProvider can exist for a given authority).

For reference, I'm trying inject it into a Fragment which uses `LoaderManager`:

```
// onViewCreated
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_DEVICES, null, new LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>() {
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(final int id, final Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(context, CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                DataContentDescriptor.Device.DEVICE_TYPE + " = ? AND " + DataContentDescriptor.Device.UDN + " != ?",
                new String[]{TYPE_SERVER, myUdn}, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(final Loader<Cursor> loader, final Cursor data) {
        deviceAdapter.setDevicesCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(final Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        deviceAdapter.setDevicesCursor(null);
    }
});
```

Some thinking so far:

- Control how the activity is instantiated and configure it with a `public static` flag to control the field. Please no, very hard to maintain.
- Within the activity, find a way to implement "isRunningInAndroidTest()" and choose a different ContentProvider authority. Better, but still a maintenance nightmare.
- Bytecode manipulation, but not sure this is even in the cards as the com.company.app is running from another APK.
- Make selection of the content provider URL part of the App design and hide it behind a ContentProviderUrlProvider (;-)) class - but this class still needs to make decisions based on the first 2 points. Frankly speaking I don't want to change SW design solely because of testing issues.

Which way could work to ensure the stubbed ContentProvider is used?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, you need different authority strings for the providers. Therefore, you need your client-side code to seamlessly use the right authority string for your build (`main` versus `androidTest`).

If your authority string is derived from the application ID, then you can synthesize the right authority string to use in your code from `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

If your authority strings are not readily generated from the `APPLICATION_ID`, you can try to add your own `buildConfigField` or `resValue` to define them in `build.gradle`, so you can reference them in your Java.
If you want to minimize code duplication, you can use manifest placeholders to define the authority strings in the manifest from values in Gradle. You can then use a common source of knowledge (e.g., `gradle.properties`) to populate both the manifest placeholder and the `buildConfigField`/`resValue`.

Now, the catch for the above paragraph is that I know it works for product flavors. I have not tried it for `androidTest`, and so it's possible that you cannot set up a different `buildConfigField` and such for `androidTest`.